# How to add onClick button to any tabs in MUI?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I wanna add onClick in button (like swap languages in google translate) to any tabs. I want like click `Swap languages` in google translate to other languages like `en -> es` to `es -> en`.

```
  const [value_s, setValue_s] = useState('one');
  const [value_t, setValue_t] = useState('four');

  const handleChange_s = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue_s(newValue);
  };
  const handleChange_t = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue_t(newValue);
  };

        <Tabs 
          value={value_s}
          onChange={handleChange_s}
        >
          {languages.map((item) => (
            <Tab key={item} label={item.Name} onClick={() => { setSource(item.langcode) }} />
          ))}
    
        </Tabs>
    
    {/* Swap languages Button*/}    
        <Tooltip title="Swap languages">
          <IconButton
            onClick={() => { setSource(target), setTarget(source) }}
          >
            <SwapHorizIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
    
    
        <Tabs
          value={value_t}
          onChange={handleChange_t}
          textColor="secondary"
          indicatorColor="secondary"
        >
          {languages.map((item) => (
            <Tab key={item} label={item.Name} onClick={() => { setTarget(item.langcode) }} />
          ))}
        </Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `value` prop to the `Tab` component. Which will allow you to toggle on the value, instead the index.

For this we need to change the initial states of the source and target.

```js
const [value_s, setValue_s] = useState("en");
const [value_t, setValue_t] = useState("es");
```

Now to can add the `value` prop to the `Tab` component, same by the `target` Tab

```js
<Tabs value={value_s} onChange={handleChange_s}>
  {languages.map((item) => (
    <Tab
      key={item}
      value={item.langcode} // the value
      label={item.Name}
      onClick={() => {
        setSource(item.langcode);
      }}
    />
  ))}
</Tabs>
```

Create a `handleSwap` function for the button

```js
const handleSwap = () => {
  setValue_s(value_t);
  setValue_t(value_s);
};
```

Which we can use like this

```js
<IconButton onClick={handleSwap}>
```